# jQuery code blows up in IE

Tags: jquery

The following code causes an error in IE:

```
$("ul.sf-menu").supersubs({
    minWidth: 10,
    maxWidth: 30,
    extraWidth: 1
}).superfish();
```

The error is saying there is an invalid argument within the jquery.js file itself when the above code is run. What is the problem?

The problem doesn't happen with this:

```
$("ul.sf-menu").superfish();
```

So supersubs is causing a problem. Any ideas why though? IE isn't telling me what the actual issue is just that an invalid argument with something. And I can't use Firebug as there is no actual JS bug it's purely an IE problem with that code.

Comment: IE is the problem.
Superfish is not jquery standard, you need to be more specific here. What jquery version are you using, what plugins, etc.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2, superfish latest, and supersubs latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong *syntactically* but the error could be happening inside `supersubs()` or `superfish()`